# InnoDB doesn't write to disk instantly. issue?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, innodb

I am working on a project using Symfony and Doctrine.

I have the following objects:

```
User, Playlist, Song
```

I am using Docrine ORM and doing a few manyTomany relationships.

- A User can have many playlists
- A Playlist can have many Users
- A Playlist can have many Songs
- A Song can have many Playlists

A 'co-worker' who had a look at the setup asked me why I was using Innodb.(I guess Doctrine uses it by default...) he said:

> "InnoDB doesn't write to disk instantly. so when mysql crashes it has to
>   try to rebuild the data that it didn't yet write to the table. often
>   times this fails and the table is lost forever"

is this true?

If so are there preventative measure against this?

If I don't want doctrine to use Innodb is it as simply as removing the manyTomany relationships in the ORM mapping?

Is there a way to relate objects with Doctrine other than Innodb?

Comment: `InnoDB doesn't write to disk instantly` is only true if autocommit is set to 0. InnoDB supports transactions and foreign keys. That is why InnoDB in combination with mysql is a RDBMS. Mysql in combination with for example MyISAM is a DBMS.

Comment: Your "co-worker" has no clue how InnoDB works. Obviously his statement is wrong and plain stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use InnoDB.  Period.

Use `BEGIN...COMMIT` around groups of statements that you want to "atomically" commit to disk.  Doing that (with InnoDB) guarantees that -- even if there is a power failure in the middle of the statements -- either *all* of the statements will be persisted to disk or *none* will be.  (Yeah, that level of consistency may be overkill for what you are doing, but it is nice to have.)

It is "true" that InnoDB delays writing to disk, but there is something up its sleeve that lets the above statement be true *even* if the power fails *after* the `COMMIT` but before it gets around to writing.  Suggest that your 'co-worker' get a degree in Computer Science, then read more about InnoDB.

As for whether Symphony and Doctrine screw up things or not, I don't know.  Still, even if they are sloppy, go with InnoDB.

With MyISAM, you are almost guaranteed to need to run a `REPAIR TABLE` after a power failure.  Not so with InnoDB.